# Windows displays old NTFS after partitioning disk for ext4 on Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, ext4, parted

I try to install a "shared" space between my Gentoo and my Windows10. So, in Gentoo, I used parted to remove all (NTFS) partitions from one of my drives and repartition it with ext4. I then mounted the partition using `mount` / fstab. After confirming that everything works smoothly on Gentoo, I switched over to Windows. And I was surprised to see my old drive name and find all the old files on it. Windows tells me that the drive is partitioned with NTFS. Even ext2fsd is not able to recognize the ext4 partition.

What is going on here? How can I get Windows to recognize the real partition?

I used the following commands:

```
# parted -a optimal /dev/sdb
> rm 1
> rm 2
> mklabel gpt
> mkpart primary 1 -1
> name 1 localshare
> quit
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp
# touch /mnt/tmp/test.txt
```

And the parted print output:

```
# parted -a optimal /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD10EACS-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  ext4         localshare
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w/e went wrong, it solved itself after rebooting both OSs a few times.
If the problem had persisted, I would have deleted the NTFS partition in Windows and recreated the ext4 partition in Linux.